# RTMP uses TCP (by default) so how suitable is it for live streaming?

Tags: tcp, udp, rtmp, broadcasting

I'm investigating RTMP, because I'm going to implement the option to broadcast a live stream from an Android device to an RTMP server. I found out that RTMP uses TCP by default and TCP guarantees delivery of packets, by retrying if they fail. Doesn't this make RTMP very unsuitable for broadcasting live streams? If the broadcaster's connection temporarily weakens, it will lead to packets that are not able to be sent in time. The stream will then fall further and further behind because of this, instead of just skipping the missed fragments.

Is this conclusion correct, or am I missing something here? I am aware btw of RMFP, which uses UDP instead of TCP. Is this what broadcasters use for live broadcasting of RTMP?

Comment: Yes RTMFP is better for broadcasting, and you should set the reliable mode to false when publishing.

Answer (score 0):

The client that is pushing the video has the option to drop a video/audio frame if it begin to fall behind.